# Python Qt: embedded html bug?

Tags: python, html, qt, html-table

Here is a strange thing that is happening... I have used embedded html with Qt Python to display a form inside the GUI/Widget. The problem is, if the cell has more content, it shows a black shadow like a box on the right side of that cell/table.

Here is an example of the code working fine:

```
    html += ("<BR><BR><table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>"
                    "<tr>"
                        "<td bgcolor='#000000'>"

                        "<table border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='4'>"
                        "<tr>"
                            "<TD WIDTH=837 bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><font size='4' color='black'><DIV align=center><B> StackOverFlow Forum<BR>YOUR FAVORITE WEB SITE</DIV></font></td>"
                        "</tr>"
                        "</table>"

                        "</td>"
                    "</tr>"
                "</table>"
                )
```

As expected, the first example shows this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+  
|                STACKOVERFLOW FORUM                 |  
|              YOUR FAVORITE WEB SITE                |  
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

then in the sequence, the same code, but with a little more content to that cell:

```
    html += ("<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>"
                    "<tr>"
                        "<td bgcolor='#000000'>"

                        "<table border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='4'>"
                        "<tr>"
                            "<TD WIDTH=837 bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><font size='4' color='black'><DIV align=center><B>STACKOVERFLOW FORUM STACKOVERFLOW FORUM STACKOVERFLOW FORUM STACKOVERFLOW FORUM STACKOVERFLOW FORUM<BR>YOUR FAVORITE WEB SITE </DIV></font></td>"
                        "</tr>"
                        "</table>"

                        "</td>"
                    "</tr>"
                "</table>"
                )
```

For the second, it shows a black shadow/box on the right-side of the table, just like this.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+||||  
|     STACKOVERFLOW FORUM STACKOVERFLOW FORUM ...    |||||  
|           YOUR FAVORITE WEB SITE                   |||||  
+----------------------------------------------------+||||
```

So, quite strange, considering that it is exactly the same code, only the second having more text inside it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an exact snippet from you code then problem may be connected with the fact that you don't have closing `</b>` tag. If that doesn't help try removing `<div>` and adding `align='center'` to `<td>`